# Recuperar un objeto en Entity framework (.NET)

Tags: entity-framework

Necesito recuperar un solo objeto de la base de datos ya que quiero cargar unas opciones especiales sobre ese registro pero a lo más que consigo llegar es a generar una lista.

¿Tendría alguna posibilidad de conseguir ese registro?

Comment: Hola @Andres deberías agregar mas información, como por ejemplo que es lo que intentaste hacer con ejemplos de código y donde estás teniendo problemas. Así como esta la pregunta es candidata a ser cerrada.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes utulizar el método [`DbSet<TEntity>.Find(params Object[] keyValues)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696418(v=vs.113).aspx)

Como parámetro le pasas el Id (mapeado al primary key) del objeto que quieres obtener y te devolverá solamente este y no una lista.

Ejemplo:

```
Persona p = Db.Personas.Find(23);
```

O si el primary key es compuesto

```
Categoria q = Db.Categorias.Find(1, 4);
```

Comment: O podría usar LINQ: `var p = Db.Personas.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == 23);`

Comment: `.Find()` tiene la ventaja de que si el objeto ya ha sido recuperado previamente y ya se encuentra en el context lo devuelve inmediatamente sin volver a la BD.